# Set the focus and position on an element whitin a Caph-list 3.1 generates navigation not working well

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, smart-tv

everyone.

I am having a little issue setting the focus to an element whitin a horizontal caph-list, and move the view to that element if the element is ahead in the list.
What I am doing is get the position index of the element whitin the array of elements that will be passed to the caph-list.

```
index = $.map(favorites, function(obj, index) {
   if (obj.id == element_id) {
   return index;
}
```

Then, when I create the caph-list I use the `initialItemIndex` parameter to ensure the element will be displayed on screen no matter its position in the list. I use this because if I do not do this the element I want to set the focus on will not be displayed on screen until I navigate to it.

```
$('#favorite-items').caphList({
  items: favorites,
  template: 'template-favorite-items',
  duration: '0.7s',
  pageBufferSize: 1,
  initialItemIndex: index,
  containerClass: 'caph-list-container-favorites'
});
```

After the caph-list object was created, then I use the `focus()` function to set the focus on that elemenet.

```
item = $('#' + element_id);
$.caph.focus.controllerProvider.getInstance().focus(item);
```

With this process I have the focus on the element I want and the element is displayed on the screen, but then the problem starts. When I try to navigate the focusables elemments on screen and press Up or Down Key on the remote control it does not work until I reach the most to right or left element on screen and the caph-list elemets make a reposition and move either to the right or to the left. After the list does a reposition of elements the navigation return to its normal behaivior, up down left right keys work as usual.

This problem with the navigation occurs when I use vertical caph-list too, but in this case I only can navigate elements with Up and Down until the reposition of the elements and only then I have full navigation control again.

Do I need to do something more besides what I have done?

Is there other way to set the focus on an element even if it is ahead in the list?

Is there a way to move to the position to the element I want to focus without affecting the navigation?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution? I'm facing with same problem. initial-item-index and data-focusable-initial-focus is not working and increasing page-buffer-size is effecting performance so bad (TV is freezing).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want to force the "focused" state of an element.

As your method:

```
> $.caph.focus.controllerProvider.getInstance().focus(item);
```

Do not work, I suggest to do that:

```
$.caph.focus.$$toAvailable(item);
```

From the documentation:

http://developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/tv/caphdocs/main.html?type=jquery&doc=tutorial&p1=7

> By default, $.caph.focus automatically makes new appended focusable
>   elements available by using MutationObserver. But, if MutationObserver
>   is not provided, you should make it available by yourself. So,
>   $.caph.focus provides $$toAvailable to manage it. This method puts
>   elements to nearest focusable finder, and bind all related events to
>   elements.

You will see that the documentation recommends to check if MutationObserver is provided, but for my experience I do not recommend to do that, cause in my case it failed.